# What are the steps to setup Liferay 7 with MariaDB?

Tags: liferay, mariadb

I am looking to setup Liferay 7 (packaged with tomcat) with MariaDB. Where can I find documentation regarding the steps?

Comment: start with the mysql instructions on https://dev.liferay.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at ["INSTALLING LIFERAY ON TOMCAT 8"](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-liferay-on-tomcat-8)

These are the steps that I have done:

1. create file */opt/liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1/portal-ext.properties*

   ```
   jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
   jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
   jdbc.default.username=root
   jdbc.default.password=
   mail.session.mail.smtp.auth=false
   mail.session.mail.smtp.host=your-smtp-server
   mail.session.mail.smtp.password=
   mail.session.mail.smtp.port=25
   mail.session.mail­.smtp.user=
   mail.session.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
   ```
2. start liferay server
3. go to welcome page and provide basic configuration (correct e-mail address  is required)
4. click "Finish configuration"
5. restart liferay server
6. go to welcome page, click "Sign In" > "forgot password" > "Send reset link"
7. receive e-mail with a reset link, provide a new password... and "Sign In"
8. voilà